# Why do we need to use 2 nominalizers もの and こと in the following sentence?

Tags: nominalization

Why do we need to use 2 nominalizers もの and こと in the following sentence?

> 素数とは、1 より大きい自然数で、正の約数が 1 と自分自身のみである**もののこと**である。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「素数{そすう}とは、1 より大{おお}きい自然数{しぜんすう}で、正{せい}の約数{やくすう}が 1 と自分自身{じぶんじしん}のみである**もの**の**こと**である。」

**In this sentence, neither the 「もの」 nor 「こと」 is a nominalizer**.

The 「もの」 here just means "the ***ones***" or "***those***" and it refers to "those/the ones among the natural numbers greater than 1 that have no positive divisors other than 1 and themselves."  That, of course, is the definition of prime numbers.

To call a word a "nominalizer", it needs to be nominalizing a ***verb***.  「もの」 is not nominalizing a verb here.

「～～のことである」 is a set phrase meaning "it is said that ~~~" or "it is defined that ~~".  Again, 「こと」 is not nominalizing a verb here.

Comment: I thought ある is a verb that もの nominalizes.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Nominalizing refers to the process of treating a verb as a noun. ある is not itself being treated as a noun rather it is modifying もの to mean "things that are". You would nominalize ある if you were talking about "being" or "existing" in general as opposed to a specific thing that exists (as in this case).

Answer (score 6):

This 「もの」 is not a nominalizer. It is a noun in the full sense of the word, meaning "thing" or the pronominal "one" (in this case I think the latter is more applicable), which is here modified by the relative clause 「1 より大きい自然数で、正の約数が 1 と自分自身のみである」.

So 「1 より大きい自然数で、正の約数が 1 と自分自身のみであるもの」 means:

> one (i.e. a number) which is a natural number greater than 1 and have no positive divisors other than one and themselves

As for the こと, it seems to be one indeed, according to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/80340/meaning/m0u/).

Under the subhead 「2⃣他の語句をうけて、その語句の表す行為や事態を体言化する形式名詞。」（”a formal noun that nominalizes the action or state expressed by another word or phrase”）, there's this subentry:

> ㋕（「…のことだ」などの形で）ある言葉の指し示す対象である意を表す。「九郎判官とは源義経の事だ」

This says that the function of this particular use 「事/こと」, in formulations like 「...のことだ」, is to state that a given word refers to some entity.

All in all, a translation of the whole sentence would be something like this:

> 素数とは1 より大きい自然数で、正の約数が 1 と自分自身のみであるものであるもの**のことである**。
>
> "Prime number" **refers to** one (i.e. a number) that is a natural number greater than 1 and have no positive divisors other than 1 and themselves.
>
> (Compare: 素数とは...であるもの**である**。→  A prime number **is** one (i.e. numbers) that is...)

Comment: So, this sentence in Japanese is not a definition of prime numbers? I am confused with prime numbers or a prime number a little bit in both answer. Anyway, 今年もよろしくお願いします。

Comment: I'm not proposing to make a distinction between the reference and the definition of a noun. When I wrote "'Prime number' refers to..." I meant it as synonymous with "'Prime number' means..." and I consider "'Prime number' means..." to be mostly the same thing as "The definition of 'prime number' is ...".

Comment: つまり、定義としては複数形より　"a"を使う方が自然かなと思ったのですが、 "The definition of 'prime number' is ..."は次のように、 "The definition of  a prime number' is  a natural number which is greater than 1 and has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself."  ここに書いてある定冠詞の使い分けの説明からするとhttps://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30999/the-articles-a-and-the-in-generic-statements?rq=1　まあ、とにかくあけましておめでとうございます。

Comment: Point... taken! 2018年も良い年にしましょう。

Comment: As @goldbrick noted correctly もの is preceded by an attributive phrase, wich together with もの becomes a nominal phrase, which in the end makes もの a nominalizer. Arguing if もの nominalizer or not is futile, it is   all a matter of prospective.